Why should the rate of evaporation of liquids depend upon the rate at which the molecules strike the surface?
This paper says:

The development of the kinetic theory of  gases led to the conclusion
that the maximum rate  at a particular temperature would be given by
the  rate at which molecules strike the surface under  equilibrium
conditions.

Why should the rate of evaporation of liquids depend upon the rate at which the molecules strike the surface?

You need to provide more context and not expect us to review the paper

@BobD The paper itself doesn't contain any more details about this. This sentence is part of the introduction and is neither cited nor elaborated.

It is not clear from your quote whether "rate at which molecules strike the surface" means the number per unit time or the speed of the molecules, but either works.
The more molecules strike the surface in a given time then the more molecules will escape from the surface and the higher the rate of evaporation. And the faster the average speed of the molecules, the more likely it is that a given molecule will escape the surface when it reaches it, so the higher the rate of evaporation.

This describes molecules in the liquid striking the surface. More molecules means more evaporation. It sounds like the question is about molecules in the gas striking the surface. More molecules means less evaporation.
